# Rcpp: Error with numerical integration. No matching constructor for initialization

Tags: r, rcpp

I have this function in R, that I am trying to replicate into Rcpp but it gives me some problems.  I get an error when trying to use the RcppNumerical integrate function. It gives me the following error code, when I try to source the function into R: 
`No matching constructor for initialization of 'BetaFunc'`.

I am a bit unsure how to use the class public Func in Rcpp that is needed in order to use the RcppNumerical integrate function.

Here is the Rcpp function that I am having trouble with:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Numer;
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> MapMat;
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> MapVec;

// Define the function to integrate over
class BetaFunc: public Func {

private:
  const double alpha;
  const double beta;
  const NumericVector vX;
  const int i;
  const NumericVector n;
  const NumericVector indx;

public:
  BetaFunc(const double alpha_, const double beta_, int i_,
           const NumericVector vX_,
           const NumericVector n_,
           const NumericVector indx_) : alpha(alpha_), beta(beta_), i(i_), vX(vX_), n(n_), indx(indx_) {}

  double operator()(const double& dZ) const {

    double Vr = Rf_dbeta(dZ, vX[i] + alpha, n[i] - vX[i] + beta, 0);
    int int_size = indx.length();

    for (int j = 0; j < int_size; j++) {

      int di = indx[j];

      Vr *= Rf_pbeta(dZ, vX[di] + alpha, n[di] - vX[di] + beta, 1, 0);

    }
    return Vr;
  }  
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
// Estimate the Bayesian posterior probability of each alternative
// being the best binomial bandit
NumericVector best_binomial_bandit(NumericVector vX, NumericVector n, double alpha = 1,
                                   double beta = 1) {
  int iK = vX.size();

  NumericVector vAns(iK);

  IntegerVector vSeq = seq(0, iK-1);

  for (int i = 0; i < iK; i++) {

    // Vector of zeros
    LogicalVector vLogi(iK);

    vLogi[i] = 1;
    // Create integervector with all values except value i
    IntegerVector indx = vSeq[vLogi < 1];
    const double lower = 0, upper = 1;
    BetaFunc f(alpha, beta, i, vX, n, indx);
    double err_est;
    int err_code;

    vAns[i] = integrate(f, lower, upper, err_est, err_code);

  }

 return vAns;

}
```

And here is the R function that is working as it should:

```
bbb <-
  function(x, n, alpha=1, beta=1) {
    k <- length(x)
    ans <- numeric(k)
    for (i in (1:k)) {
      indx <- (1:k)[-i]
      f <- function(z) {
        r <- dbeta(z, x[i] + alpha, n[i] - x[i] + beta)
        for (j in indx) {
          r <- r * pbeta(z, x[j] + alpha, n[j] - x[j] + beta)
        }
        return(r)
      }
      ans[i] = integrate(f, 0, 1)$value
    }
    return(ans)
}
```

This is just a minimal example that I am using to test the functions:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("./best_binomial_bandit.cpp")

set.seed(1)
x <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
n <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

bb_res <- bbb(x, n, 1, 1)

bb_cpp_res <- best_binomial_bandit(x, n, 0.2, 0.4)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(bbb(x, n, 1, 1),
               best_binomial_bandit(x, n, 1, 1))
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function signatures are off. Try with a reduced example based off of [`RcppNumerical`](https://github.com/yixuan/RcppNumerical)'s README.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @coatless mentioned in the comments, the function signature is off. To be precise, the last argument of the constructor for `BetaFunc` is defined as a `NumericalVector` but is called with an `IntegerVector`. From my point of view the latter is more appropriate. Changing the last argument of `BetaFunc()` to `IntegerVector` makes the example to compile. However, it is actually slower than your R code. And the results are not the same, either.